# Unexpected recycling using multiple columns when subsetting with secondary indices

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to subset a `data.table` using the method described in the `data.table` vignette https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html:

```
flights[.(c("LGA", "JFK", "EWR"), "XNA"), on = c("origin", "dest"), mult = "last"]
```

(The `mult` argument is of no relevance here.)

Here is a reproducible example that explains my problem:

```
f <- function(n) {
  set.seed(1)
  DT <- data.table(V1=sample.int(1000,n,replace=TRUE),
                   V2=sample.int(1000,n,replace=TRUE))
  return(c(
    DT[V1%in%400:600 & V2%in%800:1000, .N],
    DT[.(400:600,800:1000), .N, on=c("V1","V2")]
  ))
}
```

Based on the template, I expect to get a repeated vector of length two for any value of `n`. However:

```
> f(100)
[1]   2 201
> f(1000)
[1]  50 201
> f(10000)
[1] 392 201
>
```

The shorthand method usinng `on=` that I am trying to replicate always gives the value 201. If I modify the function a bit like this:

```
f2 <- function(n) {
  set.seed(1)
  DT <- data.table(V1=sample.int(1000,n,replace=TRUE),
                   V2=sample.int(1000,n,replace=TRUE))
  return(c(
    DT[V1%in%400:600 & V2%in%800:900, .N],
    DT[.(400:600,800:900), .N, on=c("V1","V2")]
  ))
}
```

Then it becomes clear that there is some issue with recycling among the two vectors of values that the subsetting is based on, i.e. `400:600` and `800:900`:

```
> f2(100)
[1]   2 201
Warning message:
In as.data.table.list(i) :
  Item 2 is of size 101 but maximum size is 201 (recycled leaving a remainder of 100 items)
```

Clearly, `400:600` is of length 201 and `800:900` of length 101, but I don't excpect the two of them to have anything to do with each other. I have used the exact same method in other examples and it has worked as expected. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  What output are you getting and what were you expecting?  Don't expect people to go to other sites to try and figure out what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am sorry - it got posted before I was able to complete the question. It is hopefully clearer now.

Comment: The two statements inside your `f` are not the same. Have a look at `?CJ`, like `DT[CJ(V1 = 400:600, V2 = 800:1000), on=.(V1,V2), .N, nomatch=0]` or similar.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out! And my apologies for not finding the duplicated question myself.